# Как сделать запрос в file.json при помощи SQLAlchemy?

Tags: flask, python, json, sqlalchemy

Как сделать запрос в file.json при помощи SQLAlchemy на Flask-e?

Структура json:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "Значение": "288.00", 
         "Область": "Область какая то", 
         "Город": "Город какой то"
      }, 
...
], 
   "structure": [
      "Область", 
      "Город", 
      "Значение"
   ]
}
```

Например:

```
session.query(Название таблицы(data)).filter(значение = self.значение.data).all()
```

Может, так как-то?

Comment: можешь написать бэкенд для своего формата JSON, вот пример как алхимия работает с git https://github.com/matthias-k/gitdb2

Answer (score 1):

Никак. SQLAlchemy в качестве бэкенда использует реляционные базы данных, к коим JSON ну никак не относится.

Наиболее близкое к тому, что вам нужно, можно попробовать найти гугля "JSON query language". Например для Python (раз уж используете SQLAlchemy) есть такое: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objectpath/.

---

По поводу ручного добавления данных из JSON в базу данных вот вам наметка кода, более подробно я, увы, делать не буду, читайте дальше документацию.

```
# Модель данных.
class CityData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'citydata'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    region = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    value = Column(Float)

...

# Читаем JSON-файл.
data = json.load(open('data.json'))

# Проходим по данным и добавляем их в базу.
for city in data['data']:
    cd = CityData(city['Область'], city['Город'], city['Значение'])
    session.add(cd)
session.commit()
```

Comment: а как тогда перезаписать json в БД?

Comment: Руками. Никакая мега-умная утилита не поймет вашу схему данных лучше вас, особенно подразумеваемые связи между элементами.

Поэтому составляете схему данных, создаете таблицы, пишите скрипт, который данные из JSON вставляет в соответствующие таблицы, а дальше уже пользуетесь всеми прелестями SQLAlchemy. Увы, волшебного решения тут нет (и не нужно).

Comment: Не совсем понятно " составляете схему данных, создаете таблицы, пишите скрипт, который данные из JSON вставляет в соответствующие таблицы" есть какой то пример, как это делать?

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое реляционная база данных? Если да, то вам нужно создать схему данных для данных в вашем JSON. Вы знаете, как создавать модели SQLAlchemy? Если да, то вы легко создадите модели, соответствующие вашей схеме данных. Вы умеете читать JSON-файл в Python? Если да, то следующим шагом это и делаете. Вы умеете создавать и сохранять новые экземпляры данных в SQLAlchemy? Если да, то берете, и сохраняете прочитанные из JSON данные в базу данных. Если вы чего-то из этого не умеете, читайте документацию, готовых решений под ваши данные точно не будет.

Comment: "Вы умеете создавать и сохранять новые экземпляры данных в SQLAlchemy? Если да, то берете, и сохраняете прочитанные из JSON данные в базу данных." Вот эта часть интересует). Помощь большая "читайте документацию".

Comment: Смотрите дополнение к ответу выше. Более подробно реализовывать у меня нет ни времени, ни, простите, особого желания.

Comment: "# Проходим по данным и добавляем их в базу." Вот эта часть и интересовалаю